# Checkmarx: Application contains Hardcoded connection details. This can expose database password

Tags: spring-boot, password-encryption, jasypt, checkmarx

From *Checkmarx* report:

> Application contains Hardcoded connection details. This can expose database password.

I'm using `jasypt-spring-boot` for password encryption. But in *Checkmarx*, it marks it as **medium vulnerability**.

**Dependency used:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**In PropertFile:**

`projectname.password=ENC(encrypted password)`

```java
@Value("${projectname.password}")
private String dBpassword;
```

and using the above `dBpassword` to connect to the database.

Comment: This is just a `false` positive, those tools just check some static things in your code and create a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Checkmarx is going to have a certain amount of false positives. It isn't possible for it to know every single possibility. So in this case, it doesn't realize that the @Value annotation is actually reading it from a config file. In that case you need to follow your organizations process for handling a false positive and marking  the finiding as such in Checkmarx.